# ko.cleanNode removes the jQuery .on("focusout") event

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am working with Knockout JS application. Here i have a problem when i use **ko.cleanNode(node)**, it removes *focusout* client event. i.e., before calling cleanNode method focusOut works properly on text box. After that focusOut event does not triggered. I have checked many of the stack overflow questions, I have only found the cause of this removal, not any alternative solution. Here is my Code.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  viewModel = {
    nValue: ko.observable(10)
  }
  ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("txt"));
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("txt"));
});
ko.applyBindings({
  nValue: ko.observable(100)
});
$("#txt").on("focusout", function() {
  alert("focusOut");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" data-bind="value: nValue" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="cleannode" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Knockout documentation on [disposal logic](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html#overriding-the-clean-up-of-external-data):

> When removing an element, Knockout runs logic to clean up any data associated with the element. As part of this logic, **Knockout calls jQuery’s cleanData method if jQuery is loaded in your page**. In advanced scenarios, you may want to prevent or customize how this data is removed in your application. Knockout exposes a function, `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.cleanExternalData(node)`, that can be overridden to support custom logic. For example, to prevent cleanData from being called, an empty function could be used to replace the standard `cleanExternalData` implementation

So, override the `cleanExternalData` as mentioned in the documentation:

```js
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.cleanExternalData = function () {
    // Do nothing. Now any jQuery data associated with elements will
    // not be cleaned up when the elements are removed from the DOM.
};

$("#btn").click(function() {
  viewModel = {
    nValue: ko.observable(10)
  }
  ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("txt"));
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("txt"));
});

ko.applyBindings({
  nValue: ko.observable(100)
});

$("#txt").on("focusout", function() {
  alert("focusOut");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" data-bind="value: nValue" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="cleannode" />
```

---

Looking at your code, if your intention is just updating the viewmodel's `observable` upon a click and adding a `focusOut` event handler, you don't need to `cleanNode` or `applyBindings()` or use jquery at all. You can use knokcout's [`click`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) and [`event`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) binding like this:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.nValue = ko.observable(100);

  self.increment = function() {
    self.nValue(self.nValue() + 1);
  }

  self.focusOut = function() {
    alert("Focus Out");
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" data-bind="value: nValue, event: { focusout: focusOut }" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="increment" data-bind="click: increment" />
```

Comment: Great answer. Address direct question, and also provides a more knockout-y solution.